# Nginx times out exactly after 60 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, server-sent-events

I have an app server on a backend (Rails with Puma) bound to the unix socket
this is the relevant part of nginx config

```
location /live/ {
 proxy_pass http://app; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 chunked_transfer_encoding off;
 send_timeout 300;
 proxy_send_timeout 300;
 keepalive_timeout 7200;
}
```

SSE events are coming via /live/, so I adjusted ngix config to handle all requests to this route.

The trouble is that connection closes exactly after 60sec. Here is what I see in response headers

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/event-stream
Date:Mon, 04 Nov 2013 13:41:52 GMT
Server:nginx
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:7065a7bc-3450-4fe2-b60c-33dfa8d41951
X-Runtime:0.010852
X-UA-Compatible:chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

So it seems like nginx sets the initial response to close. Why **keepalive_timeout** does not work here.

In nginx error.log I see

```
2013/11/04 13:42:52 [error] 3689#0: *9 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)   while reading upstream, client: ......., server: myapp.com, request: "GET /live/events HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ubuntu/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock:/live/events", host: "myapp.com"
```

Answer (score 19):

Just in case anyone else is in trouble with Timeout errors with Nginx + Puma + Rails, the following configuration in Nginx should increase the timeout to 605 seconds (10 minutes and 5 seconds):

```
server {
    # ... here goes your proxy configuration

    # Avoid 504 HTTP Timeout Errors
    proxy_connect_timeout       605;
    proxy_send_timeout          605;
    proxy_read_timeout          605;
    send_timeout                605;
    keepalive_timeout           605;
}
```

Comment: I am having 504 timeout at 60 seconds. I added these lines, but it still doesn't work. Still timeout at 60 seconds. Any help? I think there's something up with puma?

Comment: @AnkitChauhan it depends on which timeouts you want to have a longer duration. If your problem is related to a slow action, for example, then increasing only proxy_read_timeout may fix that.

Comment: You might also need to add:
"fastcgi_read_timeout 605;"
Depending on your environment eg php-fpm

Answer (score 8):

I think you should check your `proxy_connect_timeout` (default 60s ;) ) and your `proxy_read_timeout` (default 60s) which may cause this error. You can find the documentation here:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_connect_timeout